# Order gridview with linq data in asp

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, gridview

I am using EF6 with Linq and i am trying to order data from my Oracle database with the FileID.

This is my code to populate the data.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data"; //this is required for multi uploading
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulateUploadedFiles();
        }

    }

    private void PopulateUploadedFiles()
    {
        //Populate data
        using(Mox_Database_Entities dc = new Mox_Database_Entities())
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dc.FILE_UPLOADING.ToList();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }


    }
```

I want an ascending order for this gridview. Allowsorting = true in my gridview. I tried multiple ways to get this right but it still doesn't work.

Does anyone had this problem before?

thanks in advance for the effort.

Comment: `dc.FILE_UPLOADING.OrderBy(x => x.SomeProperty).ToList();`

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the fast reply! I Tried this before asking the question and it did not work. I removed some events from my gridview and now it's working. Thank you for your quick reply!